# Raspbian cannot resolve raspberry.org subdomains DNS for updates

Tags: raspbian, update, dns

Newbie here.. I'm having issues with accessing `archive.raspberrypi.org`.

I first thought I merely broke my installation at home but I've just installed a fresh Raspbian OS in virtualbox on a different network and I get the same DNS issues.

`ping raspberrypi.org` works fine

`ping archive.raspberrypi.org` does not resolve. (Though on the host machine running virtualbox it does respond..)

Due to this I'm unable to run `update` or `upgrade` commands.

Again, I'm a newbie but relatively comfortable working with the terminal.
Any ideas on where to look would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the result of `ping 93.93.130.214`? It's one of the IP address of the `archive.raspberrypi.org`.

Comment: Ping on that IP responds fine. It's the DNS that is the issue I suppose. resolv.conf shows the local network router as nameserver (which should be correct)

Comment: Alright, I was thinking the host/server blocked your IP address.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ping archive.raspberrypi.org

Comment: Yeah sorry, thats what I meant. Ping is just the check to see if the dns works, which it doesnt

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the output of this command to it: `dig archive.raspberrypi.org`. If you haven't `dig` available then install it with `sudo apt install dnsutils`.

Comment: ping failure is not diagnostic - many servers do not respond. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) You should post the actual output of update/upgrade attempts.

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=257445&hilit=upgrade#p1570311

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. See my answer below, topic closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's something else. It seems that the DNS resolves somethings and then other times it doesn't anymore.

Currently the above mentioned addresses currently are working fine, at this point download.docker.com isn't working..

Closing this here since I doubt this is an actual "fixable" issue.